# Does Anyone know quotes relating to Once-Returners / sakadagami

Tags: sakadagami

I desperately need quotes from either scripture or from scholars.

Answer (score 1):

The Sakadagami is mentioned in [*SN 55:24 - Sarakaani Sutta*](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn55/sn55.024.wlsh.html):

> *"Take the case of another man. He is endowed with unwavering devotion to the Buddha, the Dhamma, the Sangha. But he is not joyous in wisdom and has not gained release. Yet by destroying three fetters and weakening lust, hatred and delusion, he is a Once-returner, who will return once more to this world and put an end to suffering. That man is entirely freed from... states of woe."*

Answer (score 1):

- This might be the definition (it is, at least, one of the places where it's defined):

  > "In the Dhamma thus well-proclaimed by me — clear, open, evident, stripped of rags — those monks who have abandoned the three fetters, with the attenuation of passion, aversion, & delusion, are all once-returners who, on returning only one more time to this world, will make an ending to stress. This is how the Dhamma well-proclaimed by me is clear, open, evident, stripped of rags.

  [Alagaddupama Sutta: The Water-Snake Simile (MN 22)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/narada/nutshell.html)
- This is summarized (and clarified) in this Wikipedia article: [The four stages of attainment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_enlightenment#The_four_stages_of_attainment).
- This search returns about another 50 results from the suttas: https://suttacentral.net/search?query=%22once-returner%22&lang=en

Answer (score 0):

> Summoning up fresh courage, as a result of this glimpse of Nibbana, the Pilgrim makes rapid progress and cultivating deeper Insight becomes a Sakadagami (onnce-returner) by weakening two more Fetters — namely Sense-desire (Kamaraga) and ill-will (Patigha). He is called a Sakadagami because he is reborn on earth only once in case he does not attain Arhatship.

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/narada/nutshell.html

Answer (score 0):

**[This article](http://mahamevnawa.lk/path-ultimate-consolation/)** was written taking into account an esteemed discourse that is included in the 9th Nipata of Anguttara Nikaya - called the Sōpādisēsa Sutta.

> …….They are the Sakadāgāmi (the second state of realization of the Dhamma) disciples who have eliminated three Sanyōjana Dharma and lessened the Raga (lust), Dvesha (hatred), and Moha (ignorance). These disciples also have defilements that need to be eliminated. However, these Sakadāgāmi disciples have the ability to end all the sufferings by being born just one more time in this world, the Kāma World (Sakidēva Imanlōkan Aagantwa Dukkansantan Karōti). They are also in a state of which they are free from being born in the four low-level worlds.”